# ¿Acceder a elemento data-automation-id con Selenium?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

Les comento que estoy trabajando con Selenium, jaquery, javascript y me encontre con el siguiente problema 
Tengo una pagina(Microsoft) que esta construida totalmente dinámica tal como indico en el código:

```
<button type="button" data-automationid="FieldRenderer-name" data-selection-invoke="true" class="ms-Link nameField_f59ebb65 clickable_f59ebb65 root-203" 
title="BD Operacion">BD Operacion</button>


<button type="button" data-automationid="FieldRenderer-name" data-selection-invoke="true"  class="ms-Link nameField_f59ebb65 clickable_f59ebb65 root-203" 
title="BD Operacion nuevos recursos">BD Operacion nuevos recursos </button>
```

Como pueden ver, tengo 2 elementos cuyo nombre data-automationid="FieldRenderer-name"  es la unica referencia para poder accesar y ademas se repite con n cantidad de elementos (array)

Como puedo accesar a esos tipo de elementos ya sea con javascript, jquery o selenium, ya que hasta ahora lo mas cercano que tengo es este código que no funciona.

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("//button[@data-automation-id='FieldRenderer-name'])[1]")).
```

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("//button[@data-automation-id='FieldRenderer-name'])[1]")).
```

Esa linea es incorrecta, estás mandando un Xpath en lugar de un CSS.

Lo que yo haría es decirle a los desarrolladores que trabajen tantito y pongan ids unicos.
Si eso no se puede otra alternativa es obtener todos los elementos y verificar el texto para saber cual seleccionar, digamos que quieres el segundo boton (esto esta en Java que es lo que mas uso, pero se entiende la idea):

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("button[data-automationid='FieldRenderer-name']"))

WebElement botonCorrecto;
for(WebElement element: elements){
    if (element.getText().trim().equals("BD Operacion nuevos recursos")){
        botonCorrecto = element;
        break;
    }
}
```